# Can I use a custom iOS UI for logging in to the user's google drive account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Does the Google Drive API provide a call in the following format:

```
NSString *userAuthToken = [[GDriveService service] loginWithUsername:@"asd@gmail.com" andPassword:@"qweasdzxc"];
```

Where I can get an authorization token using which I can call all of the Google Drive API calls on the user's account?

The authorization related documentation appears to all point towards a prepackaged view controller that I will be required to present in order to authenticate the user.

Will I be able to use a completely custom UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You won't be able to use a completely custom UI.

Here's a quote from Google iOS Client Library:

> Note: Specifying the username and password is a deprecated method
>         of user authorization called ClientLogin, and does not work for all
>         user accounts.
>         Applications should instead enable users to sign in using OAuth 2,
>         such as with the gtm-oauth2 view and window controllers.

Even Google's Drive app for iOS uses OAuth for user login.

However, you can customize the prepackaged view controller they provide for OAuth login. On a separate note, their OAuth web login page is quite neat.

Hope this helps.